# Bundles or PutExtra when executing finish()

Tags: android

I would like to ask if there is a way to put `Extras` or `Bundle` when you call `finish()` method.

For example just like calling an `Activity` you can do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddListing.class);
intent.putExtra("user_id", userID);
startActivity(intent);
```

is it possible to use it in `finish()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to pass extras back to the previous Activity?

Comment: `putExtra` is not related with `finish()`. `finish()` is method to remove current activity.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to return result? If so, you should look for `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: You can use them even when you call finish().

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking to pass back results when an `Activity` is destroyed, what you should be looking for is : **startActivityForResult**.

There are two variants of `startActivityForResult()` , which allows to pass `bundle` as well in case of a necessity:

```
public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)  
public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)
```

See this example to understand the concept better:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
            }  
        });  
    }  
     // Call Back method  to get the Message from other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }
```

**SecondActivity.java:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);  
    editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                String message=editText1.getText().toString();  
                Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                setResult(2,intent);  
                finish();//finishing activity  
            }  
        });  
}
```

Comment: is there an advantage to using startActivityForResult() with a putExtra String rather than just using an Intent to move the user to the next Activity and then add a putExtra to the Intent?

Answer (score 0):

No `finish()` method is available with intent as it's parameter.If you want to pass some data back to calling Activity you can use `setResult(int resultCode, Intent intent)` before calling `finish()`. In this method you will need to pass bundle or extras in intent. And accept it in onActivityResult method in calling activity. This is the only way to pass data back to calling Activity. You can refer this link [https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Can't you just use and Intent to move the user to the MainActivity and then add a putExtra in the Intent?  Seems less complicated code versus using startActivityForResult.  Is there an advantage to using startActivityForResult() with a putExtra String?

Answer (score 0):

```
Define the userId-->after the intent initiation ,

Example,
 Intent i = new Intent(1st.this, 2nd.class);
                    String sDate = Dpcheckin.getText().toString();
                    String eDate = Dpcheckout.getText().toString();
                    String roomtext=RoomText.getText().toString();
                    i.putExtra("date1", sDate);
                    i.putExtra("date2", eDate);
                    i.putExtra("roomtext",roomtext);
                    startActivity(i);
```

where,
Mainly you need to define 2 classes inside the Intent,
1st one is the class from which you are sending the data, with(.this)extension.
2nd one is the class you are receiving the data , with (.class)extension.